# Calculate the log base n with Shift left or Shift right

Tags: c++, math, logarithm

I have a little problem.
Who knows how we can calculate the log 
base n with Shift_L or Shift_R?

for example: for n=2 we had this solution:

```
int log(int n){
int res = 0;
while((n>>=1))
    res++;
return res;
}
```

Comment: `log(x) / log(base)`. That's just basic math.

Comment: How about some simple math? ` ld(7) = log (7) / log (2)`

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming

Comment: Sorry, I do not write well. I want to solve it using shift >>

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You don't seem to want the logarithm for a base `b`, but the largest integer `n` so that `n <= log_b(x)`. If that's the case, the following function should serve your needs:

```
int intlog(double base, double x) {
    return (int)(log(x) / log(base));
}
```

Comment: Thanks! And how about doubleLog?

Comment: @AmirhosseinMehdinejad What's a "doubleLog"?

Comment: detailed log of x base n

Comment: @AmirhosseinMehdinejad What is a "detailed log"? If you mean the logarithm without truncating everything after the decimal point, just get rid of the `int` cast in the function.

Comment: Due to floating point precision, `int` casting (or applying `floor`, which is equivalent) will mess up the result in cases like `intlog(10, 1000)`: the base 10 log of 1000 is 3, but it will be stored as `2.999999[...]`, and thus casting it to `int` will return `2`.

Answer (score 9):

well this is rather a math problem instead of an actuall programming problem, if i understand your problem correctly:

`log_2 (x) = log_a (x) / log_a (2)` where a can be any base.

Therefore you could use the `math.h`'s function `log(double)`

`double res = log(x)/log(2);`

Comment: I'm just 16 years old, and i don't know so much about logarithm !

Comment: I have a Phd in engineering and I had to look this up too! :D