# How can I find logarithm of numbers to base?

Tags: javascript

I want to use dynamic base for logarithm in JavaScript.

> **ex:** logarithm `number 16` and `base 5` then output should be `1.722706232`

How to archive this using JavaScript?

I know how to archive this for base 10. Here is the code for `number 16` and `base 10`

```js
console.log(Math.log10(16));
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18874451/1169798

Comment: Thanks,  @Satpal

Answer (score 4):

Use `Math.log()`, Divide the logarithm of the number with the logarithm of the desired base.

```js
console.log(Math.log(16)/Math.log(5));
```

Comment: it should be base 10 i think. Math.log10(number)/Math.log10(base);

Answer (score 1):

> log<sub>n</sub>(x) = log<sub>*e*</sub>(x) / log<sub>*e*</sub>(n)

so

```
function generalLog(n, x) {
   return Math.log(x) / Math.log(n);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use simple mathematics to do this:

```
 log_y (x) = log_10 (x) / log_10 (y)
```